# How do configure and access up my subversion repository after I install Subversion on my GoDaddy CentOS Dedicated Server

Tags: apache, svn, version-control, centos, dedicated-server

I successfully installed subversion on my server. When I run the command:

```
which svn
```

I get the response:

```
/usr/bin/svn
```

I create a repository inside my root directory which is my httpdocs folder with the following command:

```
svnadmin create ~/svn
```

I successfully created the following files and folders and configured them and I see the following files and directories inside the svn directory:

```
conf  db  format  hooks  locks  README.txt
```

But I cannot create trunk, branch, and tag directories. In fact I cannot create directories period. Here is the command I have been using:

```
svn mkdir file:///httpdocs/svn/site
```

When I make this command the message I get is the following:

```
svn: Could not use external editor to fetch log message; consider setting the
$SVN_EDITOR environment variable or using the --message (-m) or --file (-F) options
svn: None of the environment variables SVN_EDITOR, VISUAL or EDITOR are set, and no
'editor-cmd' run-time configuration option was found
```

Also When I type in url:

```
http://mydomain.com/svn
```

I get the follwoing message:

```
404 - Not Found
```

What do I need to do to configure my repository, check to see if my repository is actually working. Oh and I did run the following command:

```
svnserve -d
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I create a repository inside my root directory which is my httpdocs folder with the following command...

That's not how you get Subversion to work with Apache httpd if that's what you're trying to do. You need the mod_dav and mod_dav_svn modules for Apache. You might have to recompile Apache to get these.

Once you get mod_dav and mod_dav_svn installed, you need to configure your httpd.conf file (or put a configuration file under your httpd's `conf.d` depending how it's configured on your system) for it to work.

In the end, it's not all that difficult. Most Apache installations have mod_dav and mod_dav_svn added in, and you can see if your http.conf file is configured correctly. The on line Subversion manual will have [everything you need](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html) to get it working.

> svn: Could not use external editor to fetch log message; consider setting the
>   $SVN_EDITOR environment variable or using the --message (-m) or --file (-F) options
>   svn: None of the environment variables SVN_EDITOR, VISUAL or EDITOR are set, and no
>   'editor-cmd' run-time configuration option was found

Read the message. It says *Could not use external editor* because you didn't specify one. Again the Subversion on line manual explains it in [detail](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externaleditors.html).

Basically, when you commit a change in Subversion, you need to create a commit message. This can be done in two ways:

- You use the `-m` option like `svn commit -m "This is my commit message"`.
- You set the variables `SVN_EDITOR`, `VISUAL`, or `EDITOR` to the name of the program you want to use. For example, in Windows, you'd say `C:> set EDITOR=notepad.exe`. On Unix, you'd say something like `$ export EDITOR=vi`. Subversion first checks the value of the `SVN_EDITOR` variable, then `VISUAL`, then `EDITOR`. If none of them are set, it gives you the error you saw.

Why did you get it on the `svn mkdir` command?

Because you use the URL form of the command, it will make the directory, then commit the change, thus the need for a commit message. This should work:

```
svn mkdir -m"Adding the site directory to my repository" file:///httpdocs/svn/site
```

Now, you need to move your repository out of your HTTPDOCs directory. That's a very bad thing to have because it hurts your web server.

If you don't want to use the `file://` protocol, you can use `svnserve`. This is a built-in Subversion repository server and uses the `svn://` protocol. Observe:

```
$ svnadmin create my_repos   #Creates the repository
$ vi my_repos/conf/svnserve.conf  #See footnote 1 below
$ vi my_repos/conf/passwd         #See footnote 1 below
$ svnserve -r my_repos -d
$ svn mkdir -m "Making basic directory layout svn://localhost/trunk \
> svn://localhost/tags svn://localhost/branches
$ export SVN_EDITOR="vi"
```

Your repository also becomes accessible to all the machines on your network too. Using svnserve is much simpler than Apache httpd, but there are a few issues:

- You can't run multiple instances of `svnserve` since it wants to use port 3690 and it doesn't like to share. With Apache httpd, you can have multiple repositories.
- Security setup with svnserve is limited. With Apache, I can use Windows Active directory or LDAP or I can configure it manually.
- Some web based subversion repository browsers don't like svnserve.

By the way, if you haven't, go through the [Subversion on line manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/). It's one of the best manuals I've seen for any open source project.

---

<sup>1</sup> When you setup your repository using `svnserve`, you need to edit the `svnserve.conf` file by enabling the line `password-db = passed` which is about line #20 in the file. Then you have to edit the `passed` file (located in the same directory) to configure the users and their passwords. Both are very straight forward, but easy to forget, and if you don't do it, you can't commit anything into your repository.

Answer (score 1):

when you need to trunk branches and tags than you have to need the download `import_dirs.copy`

than after than `cd /location/import_dirs.copy`  than run than command

```
cd /data/svn/import_dirs.copy/ 
svn import  file:///location of repos/reposname/  -m "inital message"
```

this is the example of it.....

```
cd /home/raj/import_dirs.copy/
svn import  file:///srv/svn/nmg/  -m "inital message"
```

than trunk branches and tags have been done